# Calculations between nested forms, Gravity Forms

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

I'm using Gravity Forms & Nested Forms.

I'd like to add numbers up between child entries but unsure on how to enable the merge tags on the parent form so I can do Calculations based on the Numbers entered in the child forms.

[My Parent Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SCRMx.jpg)

I'd like to calculate a Total Chargeable Time as seen in the screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

The merge tags must be manually entered on in the formula setting a calculation-enabled Number or Product field on the parent form. It sounds like you're looking for the `:count` modifier (i.e. `{Nested Form:1:count}`).

Full documentation here:

https://gravitywiz.com/documentation/gravity-forms-nested-forms/

Support here:

http://gravitywiz.com/support/

Comment: Found it last night and got it working with Sum as well, so handy its all working now. Thank you for the help.